# Swift 4 camera view, why does this crash on iPad and not on iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm building an app for iPad that takes pictures. Why does this code crash on iPad but yet works fine on iPhone? I'm assuming it has something to do with device capabilities? I'm using an iPad Pro 12.9 running iOS 12.1 and Swift 4.1 with Xcode 10. I have added the required lines in the `info.plist` about camera privacy and photos privacy. Thanks for your guidance.

It crashes at the line with the `guard` statement.

```
 private func configure() {
    // Preset the session for taking photo in full resolution
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    // Get the front and back-facing camera for taking photos
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)

    for device in deviceDiscoverySession.devices {
        if device.position == .back {
            backFacingCamera = device
        } else if device.position == .front {
            frontFacingCamera = device
        }
    }

    currentDevice = backFacingCamera

    guard let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice) else {
        return
    }

    // Configure the session with the output for capturing still images
    stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    // Configure the session with the input and the output devices
    captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
    captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

    // Provide a camera preview
    cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    view.layer.addSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.frame

    // Bring the camera button to front
    view.bringSubviewToFront(cameraButton)
    captureSession.startRunning()

    // Toggle Camera recognizer
    toggleCameraGestureRecognizer.direction = .up
    toggleCameraGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleCamera))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(toggleCameraGestureRecognizer)

    // Zoom In recognizer
    zoomInGestureRecognizer.direction = .right
    zoomInGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(zoomIn))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(zoomInGestureRecognizer)

    // Zoom Out recognizer
    zoomOutGestureRecognizer.direction = .left
    zoomOutGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(zoomOut))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(zoomOutGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func toggleCamera() {
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()

    // Change the device based on the current camera
    guard let newDevice = (currentDevice?.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) ? frontFacingCamera : backFacingCamera else {
        return
    }

    // Remove all inputs from the session
    for input in captureSession.inputs {
        captureSession.removeInput(input as! AVCaptureDeviceInput)
    }

    // Change to the new input
    let cameraInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput
    do {
        cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newDevice)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    if captureSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
        captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
    }

    currentDevice = newDevice
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
}
```

Comment: Hey facing same issue but on Iphone device let me Know whats the solution have you sort it

Answer (score 1):

It's device capabilities. iPads have wide-angle camera.

```
 let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
```